# Conditional mapping with Feeds

Tags: rules, feeds

Using Feeds, I am trying to import products from a source CSV.  One of the CSV columns contains the quantity of items in stock.  The goal is to map it to a product 'Stock Status' field.  If the quantity field is greater than zero, 'Stock Status' is 'In Stock'; if zero, 'Stock Status' is 'Out of Stock'.

I didn't see a Feeds Tamper plugin or combination of plugins that would work and my attempts to use Rules so far have failed.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to just put a formula into a spreadsheet and alter your source csv.

Else you could write your own feeds tamper plugin.

Create an empty file called 'stock.inc' and place it into the feeds_tamper/plugins directory. Add this to it:

```
<?php
$plugin = array(
  'form' => 'feeds_tamper_stock_form',
  'callback' => 'feeds_tamper_stock_callback',
  'name' => 'Calculate stock',
  'multi' => 'direct',
  'category' => 'Other',
);

function feeds_tamper_stock_form($importer, $element_key, $settings) {
  return array(
    'help' => array(
      '#markup' => t('Sets the stock status'),
    ),
  );
}

function feeds_tamper_stock_callback($result, $item_key, $element_key, &$field, $settings, $source) {
  $field = $result->items[$item_key] > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock' ;
}
```

Clear your cache.

I have not tested this but I believe it will get you close.

Comment: I can't control the format of the spreadsheet so I went with your Feeds Tamper approach.  I downloaded the 'Feeds Tamper PHP' module and added 3 lines of code.  It seems like a simpler and more maintainable solution.  Thank you for your guidance.  I didn't know whether to use Rules or Feed Tamper.  You saved me hours and a lot of uncertainty over whether I used the right approach or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using J. Reynolds' answer as a guide, I downloaded Feeds Tamper PHP and added the following code to a feeds tamper PHP plugin.

```
if ($item['quantity'] > 0) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 2;
}
```

The destination field is of 'List (text)' type with 1 representing 'in stock' and 2 representing 'out of stock'.